# how to install satchmo project in django?

Tags: django, satchmo

I'm having a problem with satchmo project in django. I want to know how do I install it properly to see it working.

So far what I have tried is that I have created a directory store and installed satchmo in that. But from the Satchmo documentation it's not very clear what do I have to do after that.

Comment: I'd be amazed if you could make Satchmo work with any recent version of Django. It hasn't been updated for years.

Comment: That's why I'm using Django 1.4.

Comment: But don't. 1.4 is massively outdated, and totally insecure.

Comment: Yeah But I just found out they have used Django 1.8

Comment: They haven't updated their installation I guess

Comment: Look the point is that Satchmo is a dead project. You shouldn't try to use it.

Comment: No I'm just using for learning purposes